# Reading .csv file using shell script breaking conditional loop logic

Tags: linux, shell, csv, centos, xmlstarlet

I am creating a shell script to read user and project name from .csv file and add the user is config.xml file.

[image]

Below is the sample xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<hudson>
<authorizationStrategy>
<roleMap type="globalRoles">
  <role name="Employee" pattern=".*">
     <assignedSIDs>
      <sid>abc</sid>
      <sid>cde</sid>
      <sid>user1</sid>
    </assignedSIDs>
  </role>
</roleMap>

<roleMap type="projectRoles">
  <role name="project_a">
<permissions/>
    <assignedSIDs>
      <sid>abc</sid>
      <sid>cde</sid>
      <sid>user1</sid>
    </assignedSIDs>
  </role>
<role name="project_b">
 <permissions/>
    <assignedSIDs>
      <sid>abc</sid>
      <sid>cde</sid>
    </assignedSIDs>
  </role>
 </roleMap>
</authorizationStrategy>
</hudson>
```

Below is the code snippet

```
while IFS=',' read -r user projectName;
    do
        echo "start"
        echo "userid is : $user"
        echo "projectRoles is: $projectName"

    #check if user is present in global role
    a=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/hudson/authorizationStrategy/roleMap[@type='globalRoles']/role[@name='Employee']/assignedSIDs/sid = '$user'" config.xml)
    b=true
    c=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/hudson/authorizationStrategy/roleMap[@type='projectRoles']/role[@name='$projectName']/assignedSIDs/sid='$user'" config.xml)
    d=true

    if [ $a -eq $b ];
    then
        echo " $user is present in global roles"
        #Check if the user is present in project role

        if [ $c -eq $d ];
        then
            echo " Cannot add $user, as it is already present in $projectName "
        else
            echo "$user has been added to project"
            echo " To step out of the script, press CTRL + c key "
        fi          
    else 
        echo " $user is not present in global roles"
    fi  
sleep 3;
done <addExcelUser.csv
```

Issues which i am facing: 
1) the variable "c" output is false when i am using it inside while loop,but when i used it without using while command to read .csv file, it shows true.
because of this my whole logic goes wrong.

for eg: user1 is present in global role and in project_a, so variable "a" shows true, and when compared with variable b in if expression, it results true.
but variable c shows false even when the user1 is present in that project role (project_a). Ideally it should be true.

My guess is the somewhere the loop is breaking while reading .csv file and making the whole logic wrong.

Please help with your expertise.

Comment: i used `if [[ "$a" -eq "$b" ]];` and the error "true: integer expression expected" is gone now. But only first if condition is getting correct output.next if condition is showing wrong output.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer. The issue with my script was `if [ $a -eq $b ];` loop.

with this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42968/bash-integer-expression-expected-using-read-test) i learnt about using [[ ]] which handles such exceptions.

I used `if [[ "$a" = "$b" ]]` expression to evaluate the condition which resulted in true and made my logic work. Any suggestion of best practice is welcomed from you guys. I have lot to learn :)

Comment: `[ "$a" = "$b" ]` should work too. I would suggest dropping the `b` and `d` variables and just writing `[[ "$a" = true ]]`. Also, use more descriptive variable names, e.g. `inGlobal` and `inProject` instead of `a` and `c`.

Comment: Thanks @npostavs for sharing best practice with me. I would surely do the changes in my script to make it more readable.